# Why did Tyrion look displeased?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07),

> Jon and Dany have sex with each other

It is shown that Tyrion is outside and sees that this is going on. He appears to have a disapproving face.

What is his reason for this disapproval? He doesn't seem to have any reason to be against this.

Comment: It's your interpretation of a a facial expression...I might call it **concern** rather than disapproval. As such, the question is entirely subjective and answers would be speculative.

Comment: I don't think this is primarily opinion based. The scene had clear focus on Tyrion and an attempt to display his concerns if not disappointment. So I think there can be some logical explanation to that scene based on his past conversations and statements. I personally am not voting to close this question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, so ask why he's *concerned* then.

Comment: This question is clearly asking for the interpretation of a character's expression (that clearly meant *something* at least) and the feelings behind it. It seems to be properly reasonable by analysing the current situation and the character's own motivations and emotional state right now. We don't necessarily need the character to tell us straight on in the next episode *why* he looked that way to provide a proper answer. I know we're all tired of *GoT* speculation, but let's not lose our grip of what a proper character analysis question is.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned the widespread speculation (supported by serious hints) about Tyrion having somehow betrayed Daenerys.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Tyrion has sacrificed a lot, including loyalty to his family, to be Daenerys' advisor and hand. He believes in her and loves her as a queen and agrees with her vision of the new world she wants to build.

He, along with Varys, has tasked himself primarily with keeping her potential madness in check (indeed, this is something Daenerys explicitly tasked Varys with) - this is highlighted in many episodes but is made explicit in a scene with Cersei in "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07):

> CERSEI: Eventually, you want everyone to bend the knee to her.
>
> TYRION: Yes.
>
> CERSEI: Why?
>
> TYRION: (PAUSE) Because **I think she will make the world a better place**.
>
> CERSEI: You said she'd destroy King's Landing
>
> TYRION: She knows herself. **She chose an advisor who would check her worst impulses** instead of feeding them
> <sub>—"The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07)</sub>

Tyrion strongly believes in Daenerys' "better place", but also has expressed deep concern (sometimes even hints of regret) about the things she does (when he watched Drogon burn the Lannister troops, or when he walked through the field of ash, or when he tried to stop Daenerys from burning the Tarlys).

He already recognised this problem with the Jon-Daenerys romance at Dragonstone, in "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones, S07E06)*, when he saw Daenerys risk everything (her own and her dragons' life, along with any hope for a new world) at the first mention of Jon Snow being in danger.

Seeing Jon Snow entering her quarters (and correctly inferring that their romantic/sexual tension had come to fruition) struck him with deep concern because now he knows **his own influence to keep Daenerys' worst impulses in check has been compromised**, and moreover Jon will be able to influence her, or have her risk her life again whenever he is next in danger.

**Out-of-universe** it is supposed to echo the concern going through the audience's mind, as we (watching this scene narrated by Bran) are experiencing the [dramatic irony](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dramatic-irony) of this sex scene, and are having our own reservations about an incestual sex scene between an aunt and nephew, and are having our own thoughts and concerns about the political and romantic strife this will cause later on, when they find out. Tyrion's expression of concern serves narratively, but also out-of-universe to echo our own concern.

---

### Update: From the mouth of the actor who plays Tyrion, Peter Dinklage

In *[Game of Thrones: Cast Commentary on A Union of Fire and Ice (HBO)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq0_mMin14Y)*, Peter Dinklage, the actor who plays Tyrion, comments on this very scene and gives some insight into why he reacts the way he does:

> It's **dangerous** for everybody involved. I'm sure it's good for both of them in the moment, but ...
>
> You don't even get the relief of how beautiful it could be or should be, it's ..."No! It's not good!". But it *should* be, "but it's *not*!".
>
> It's *Game of Thrones* - there's a long history of **romance not ending well** on this show.
> <sub>—Peter Dinklage, *[Game of Thrones: Cast Commentary on A Union of Fire and Ice (HBO)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq0_mMin14Y)*</sub>

Comment: Isn't it uncle and niece? Also targs like to inbreed so seems normal there.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I'd have to be quoted where I say it isn't normal - I merely said Tyrion's expression was probably meant to mirror the audience's own concerns about this factually incestuous relationship - whether the incest itself is a problem for the audience member is irrelevant. The point is Jon and Dany will have problems once they find out about this, and this is the sort of thing an audience member could be concerned with while they experience the dramatic irony. `Isn't it uncle and niece?` No.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No. Danny is Jon's aunt. Check: http://static6.uk.businessinsider.com/image/57768552dd0895bb3e8b4b8f-1200/ti%20graphics%20game%20of%20thrones%20family%20stark%20targaryen%20tree.png

Comment: "He already recognised this problem with the Jon-Daenerys romance at Dragonstone, in "Beyond the Wall" (Game of Thrones, S07E06), when he saw Daenerys risk everything (her own and her dragons' life, along with any hope for a new world) at the first mention of Jon Snow being in danger."

I think this precisely sums up Tyrion's worries.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Yes. That would be why I included it.

Comment: Excellent answer btw! A small addendum to it: https://www.quora.com/Judging-by-the-closing-ship-scene-during-the-S7-finale-is-it-possible-that-Tyrion-has-known-that-Jon-is-a-Targaryen-Does-Tyrion-see-that-this-is-going-to-be-a-tricky-relationship-between-Jon-and-Daenerys-and-thats-why-he-looks-so-forlorn/answer/Annissa-Clarke

Comment: “Also targs like to inbreed so seems normal there.” Sure, although some think that’s how they ended up with the Mad King.

Comment: I also think there is an element that Tyrion might have romantic feelings for Dany also, but I do think the reveal of Jon's parentage will be an internal struggle for Jon, and is dangerous in the sense the Northerners may not feel like they can trust him, other people may want to kill him, and even Dany will realize he has better claim to the Throne than she does. It defiantly is a monkey-wrench situation, despite that I think they do love each other.

Comment: @DarthLocke Originally, Jon and Tyrion both fall in love with Arya and Arya chooses Jon which puts a massive strain on Tyrion and Jon's friendship, so it could be possible that we're seeing elements of that here - I might be on-board with it, except that I see absolutely no evidence anywhere for this.

Comment: @GhotiandChips What's Arya got to do with this? You mean Dany, right?

Comment: @NVZ No, I mean GRRM's original drafts for the book series which he intended to be 3 books long, not 7.

Comment: @GhotiandChips So who's Arya? The same Arya in the TV show?

Comment: From GRRM: `Exiled, Tyrion will change sides, making common cause with the surviving Starks to bring his brother down, and falling helplessly in love with Arya Stark while he’s at it. His passion is, alas, unreciprocated, but no less intense for that, and it will lead to a deadly rivalry between Tyrion and Jon Snow.` and `[Arya] realizes that she has fallen in love with Jon, who is her half-brother. Their passion will continue to torment Jon and Arya throughout the trilogy, until the secret of Jon’s true parentage is finally revealed in the last book.` @NVZ

Comment: Thanks. And I suppose Arya is a much older girl in that story.

Comment: @NVZ It's more that Jon is much younger in the books. Arya is 8 when the books start and Jon is 14, leaving a 6 year gap. That gap might be smaller in GRRM's original drafts - I'm not sure, I stayed away considering potential spoilers. There are big changes like Jaime being the Mad King archetype, rather than Cersei.

Answer (score 7):

Although an excellent answer is above, *The New York Times* posted an [interview](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/29/arts/television/game-of-thrones-season-7-finale-director-jon-snow.html) with Director Jeremy Podeswa today. He directly addresses this question,

> **When Jon and Dany hook up, we know it’s incest, but they don’t. So why
>   does Tyrion look troubled? Why the reaction shot from him?**
>
> From my point of view, Tyrion always seemed three steps ahead. As long
>   as there is a professional alliance between Dany and Jon, that’s
>   something that everybody wants. We can imagine that that’s a helpful
>   alliance. But when things get personal, then people make decisions
>   based on their emotions, and that can complicate matters going
>   forward, so I think he sees the potential here for things to get very
>   messy. Usually, historically, nothing good comes out of relationships
>   becoming more complicated! [Laughs] It’s also a question of what’s
>   going to be his role within this new alliance, right? So there’s a
>   kind of caution here.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Tyrion knows about Jon's parents.

That is why he looks so confused. On one hand, he wants a next in line for Daenarys, on the other, he feels this is wrong, especially because they (Dany and Jon) don't know. Unlike Cersei and Jaime did.

**How**
Varys told him...
How does Varys know? In season 1, Varys visits Ned Stark a few times in his cell. On the last visit, Varys informs him that they will let him "take the black" and live out his days with his bastard son if he pleads guilty and asks for mercy.
Ned asks for one last favor and asks for ink and paper. In 7 season, it has never been revealed what was in that letter or to who it was written too.
He most likely wrote it for Jon or about Jon, so that he didn't take the truth with him to his grave.
Why would he risk this with Varys?

- Varys use to advise the Targaryen Mad King, so he was originally a Targaryen supporter.
- Jon is relatively safe at The Wall from the Lannisters claws if it gets out.
- Varys seems to be the only ally Ned has at that moment.

After 7 seasons, that letter is forgotten by most viewers so that it will have enough shock effect when it is revealed.
Varys trusts Tyrion, so it would not be such a surprise that he told him.
But why would they keep it a secret?

They have no proof other than Ned Starks letter.
They have no reason to reveal this to either Dany or Jon, it could only bring internal disputes.

**Why**
If Daenerys has to hear this truth from a crippled boy with visions and a drop out maester who is in the Night's Watch, she will be skeptical about it, like she is about everything without proof.
But if 2 of her trusted advisors confirm this news, she will be more open to the truth.
Varys was also the Spider when serving the Mad King, he most likely knew the truth behind Rheagar and Lyanna's relationship and might even know about their secret wedding.
Let Howland Reed visit Wintefell at that same time and confirm that Ned came out of that tower with baby Jon, and all the North will believe it too, because everyone knows the story of how Ned killed Ser Arthur Dayne with Howland Reed at his side.

The big "Jon is a Targaryen" reveal must be well supported, not just to convince Dany, but everyone who is convinced before it is revealed is one less doubter and easier to explain why they will all accept this story as truth.

Comment: There is strong evidence that letter Ned wrote was to go to Yoren: *I was set to leave, wagons bought and loaded, and a man comes with a boy for me and a purse of coin, and a message, never mind who it’s from. Lord Eddard is to take the Black, he says to me, wait, he will being going with you. Why do you think I was there? Only something went queer."*

Comment: @Skooba A message is not neccerly a letter,.. and I don't see why Ned would bother to smuggle out a letter to Yoren just to have a travel party when he goes to The Wall.